# Object mathematics Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with my object in JavaScript.
please observe the following code:

```
function Bullet(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log(this.x);

    this.fire = function() {
        this.x++;
        console.log(this.x);
    };

    this.draw = function(ctx, bulletImage) {
        ctx.drawImage(bulletImage, this.x, this.y);
    };
};
```

The problem is with the this.fire();
What I'm trying to do is run this from my main script:

```
bullet = new Bullet(20, 80);
bullet_loop = setInterval(bullet.fire, 11);
```

and then it should execute the `this.fire();` function until I cancel the interval.
This goes as planned, however.

When the object is created it has the line `console.log(this.x);`
this returns `"20"` as it should, but when the `this.fire();` function is called
it should add `1` up to `this.x` as you would expect it would when you issue `this.x++;`.
However when it reaches the `console.log(this.x);` line in the `this.fire();` function
it returns `NaN`.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback isn't properly bound.  The easiest way is to just wrap the command in a function:

```
bullet_loop = setInterval(function() { bullet.fire(); }, 11);
```

You can also use the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
bullet_loop = setInterval(bullet.fire.bind(bullet), 11);
```

Comment: This solved the problem completely, thanks alot I was really suck on this one~!

I will mark this as answer in 10 minutes, again thanks alot!

Comment: You have to be careful about what `this` is when you deal with functions and callbacks

Comment: The actual problem is that the `fire` function gets called with the wrong context (i.e. `this` != your *bullet* variable, it's the global `window` object here!).

Comment: @ComFreek you could also do `bullet_loop = setInterval(bullet.fire.bind(bullet), 11);`

Comment: @Nirk This is probably the cleanest possible solution ;) I've added it to your answer.